# Simple raw terminal program windows

Tags: java, windows, terminal, stty

I need to be able to get input without the user pressing enter in java. As far as I can tell this cannot be done without JNI/JNA which I would like to avoid. So I am looking for a small program that could do this for me and then undo it when called again (with different arguments maybe?) It can be in any language (preferably a compiled one), but preferably it could be compiled without  MS visual studio because I would rather not install that.

Basically is there a windows equivalent of `stty raw` that I could call from Java?

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely still need JNI. Many libraries already exist for this however. You can try JCurses here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/ however it has not been updated in a 3 years!

I believe if you are on UNIX/Linux that Lanterna (https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/) also has something for this purpose (and it's also a lot more up to date and easy to use).

I don't think anything more specific and lightweight exists without you having to write one yourself.